# How do you determine who has the best claim to lost and hidden objects?

Tags: united-kingdom, ownership

This is a question that relates to the nature of the land -- property law. How do you determine who has a claim over an object they found and in which situations would they have a claim?

Say, person A was invited to person B's house so they could dine together. Person A found a £60 note in front of person B's house. Person A also found a £20 note on person B's doorstep and another in person B's kitchen. None of these were the property of person B, originally.

Who, in this case, would have the best claim to the property found? Why?

Comment: Are you looking for answers about money or about specific objects?

Comment: An answer which focuses on who has the best claim of property with respect to money.

Comment: You could as well as remove the last one (in the kitchen). I mean, "I've found this microwave oven in your kitchen; I've found this silver tray in your living room", etc.

Comment: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-stoke-staffordshire-39119990

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The owner has the best claim

The finder of lost property [must](https://notlost.com/the-definitive-guide-to-lost-property-laws-in-the-uk/):

1. Hand it to the venue owner who will make reasonable efforts to find the owner.
2. Hand it to police if it is a type of lost property police will accept - cash is such a type who will make reasonable efforts to find the owner
3. Make reasonable efforts to find the owner.

If, after a reasonable time the owner can’t be found, the person with custody may treat it as their own.

Comment: To back this up with an actual conviction - https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-stoke-staffordshire-39119990

Comment: police also accepts ID documents or other such items.

Comment: I think a legal alternative is "completely ignore the lost property".